# unchecked checkbox still returns true on checkbox.is(":checked")

Tags: jquery

I have two checkboxes, 'pickup', and 'delivery'.
Only one of them can be checked, so when one is checked and I check the other, the first one will be unchecked.

When I check A, and then immediately check B, A unchecks as expected.
However when I console log if it is checked or not using `.is(":checked")`, both return true (this happens only when checking one if the other is already selected).

What am I doing wrong ?

here is the same code in codepen: https://codepen.io/BoLeynen/pen/RwKNwQY?editors=1010

```js
let deliveryCheckbox = $("#checkbox-delivery")
let pickupCheckbox = $("#checkbox-pickup")

deliveryCheckbox.on('change', function(e){
  check(e);
});
pickupCheckbox.on('change', function(e){
  check(e);
});


function check(e){
  var clickedCheckbox = e.target.id;
  let pickupCheckboxValue = pickupCheckbox.is(':checked');
  let deliveryCheckboxValue = deliveryCheckbox.is(':checked');
  
  if(clickedCheckbox ==='checkbox-pickup'){
    deliveryCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
    console.log( 'delivery checked: ', deliveryCheckboxValue, '   pickup checked: ', pickupCheckboxValue)


  }else if(clickedCheckbox === 'checkbox-delivery'){
    pickupCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
    console.log( 'delivery checked: ', deliveryCheckboxValue, '   pickup checked: ', pickupCheckboxValue)

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  
  <input type="checkbox" name="delivery" value="delivery" id="checkbox-delivery">
  <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
  </br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pickup" value="pickup" id="checkbox-pickup">
  <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
</form>
```

Comment: nothing wrong in your code just check you defined variable first then printing console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the flag from **before** you unchecked the checkbox. You're doing:

```
let pickupCheckboxValue = pickupCheckbox.is(':checked');
let deliveryCheckboxValue = deliveryCheckbox.is(':checked');
```

then **later** you're doing

```
pickupCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
```

or similar for the other one. That doesn't have any effect on the boolean value you already have stored in `pickupCheckboxValue` and `deliveryCheckboxValue`.

If you want to know the state *after* the change, get the state after the change:

```js
let deliveryCheckbox = $("#checkbox-delivery")
let pickupCheckbox = $("#checkbox-pickup")

deliveryCheckbox.on("change", function(e){
    check(e);
});
pickupCheckbox.on("change", function(e){
    check(e);
});

function check(e){
    var clickedCheckbox = e.target.id;
    
    if (clickedCheckbox ==="checkbox-pickup") {
        deliveryCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
    } else if (clickedCheckbox === "checkbox-delivery") {
        pickupCheckbox.prop("checked", false);
    }
    let pickupCheckboxValue = pickupCheckbox.is(":checked");
    let deliveryCheckboxValue = deliveryCheckbox.is(":checked");
    console.log( "delivery checked: ", deliveryCheckboxValue, "   pickup checked: ", pickupCheckboxValue)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  
  <input type="checkbox" name="delivery" value="delivery" id="checkbox-delivery">
  <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
  </br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pickup" value="pickup" id="checkbox-pickup">
  <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
</form>
```

***But***, we have radio buttons for exactly this situation: Mutually-exclusive choices:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
  
  <input type="radio" name="delivery-option" value="delivery" id="checkbox-delivery">
  <label for="delivery">Delivery</label>
  </br>
  <input type="radio" name="delivery-option" value="pickup" id="checkbox-pickup">
  <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
</form>
```

Also note that your `for` values don't match your `id` values. You could use containment rather than `for` and `id`:

```html
<form action="">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="delivery-option" value="delivery">
        Delivery
    </label>
    </br>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="delivery-option" value="pickup">
        Pickup
    </label>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```